# How can i put colon after number in lof and lot pages with tocloft package?

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

In my project i use `tocloft` package, and by default, after numbers in lot and lof pages colons are absent.

In `tocloft` document i saw some commands to adjust that, but it did not work. For example, as i understand, when used with `tocloft` package the following command puts colon after numbers:

```
\renewcommand{\cftaftersnum}{:}
```

I want my lof and lot pages to be seen as,

```
[fig or table number]: ***** caption or explanation *****    [page number].
```

Comment: Please post a minimal version (compilable!) of your document, not just fragments of code only!

Answer (score 4):

You are very, very close. You need to issue the following instructions

```
\renewcommand\cftfigaftersnum{:}
\renewcommand\cfttabaftersnum{:}
```

after loading the `tocloft` package.